# change directory and run command with #!bin/bash file

Tags: linux, bash

I need a cron job which changes the directory and runs a command.

Commands:

```
cd /var/www/domain.com/httpdocs
sake cron/test
```

I wrote this .sh file (/var/here/and/there/test.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/domain.com/httpdocs
sake cron/test
```

I "chmoded" the file:

```
chmod 777 test.sh
```

When I run it:

sh /var/here/and/there/test.sh

the output is this:

```
[1] : No such file or directoryrons/test.sh: line 2: cd: /var/www/domain.com/httpdocs
[2] Can't find ./sapphire/cli-script.php or ./cli-script.php
```

(the second line is from the sake command, which only is successfull when executed in the correct directory)

thx

Comment: try to use bash instead of sh to run it. rename your test.sh to something else...

Comment: no sorry, dont work ... the same output

Comment: `chmod 777` is excessive; it gives all users permission to read, modify, or execute the file.  Consider `chmod 755` instead, which gives write access only to the owner.  (Even if there's nobody else on the system, it's a good habit.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a stray carriage return (`\r`) at the end of your `cd` command.  The shell assumes the `'\r'` is part of the directory name.  When it prints it in the error message, the cursor jumps to the beginning of the line, and the remainder of the message overwrites whatever was there.

Make sure that test.sh uses Unix-style line endings, not Windows-style endings.  (This may be a side effect of whatever editor you used to create it.)

Are you running under Cygwin by any chance?

`dos2unix --help`

(Warning: Unlike most filters, `dos2unix` converts files *in place*.)

Comment: thx, that was it :-) I uploaded the file with my FTP client and dont created it in the shell ...

Answer (score 0):

Does directory `/var/www/domain.com/httpdocs` actually exist? Can you manually `cd /var/www/domain.com/httpdocs` from a shell on that system without error?

Comment: yes it exists: [root@pserver httpdocs]# pwd
/var/www/domain.com/httpdocs
[root@pserver httpdocs]#